# Share a program between 2 or more OS in one machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, windows-8.1, multi-boot

I was wondering if it is possible somehow to share or install a program in a common drive shared between 2 or more OS in one machine with dual (or more) boot?

For example, I have Windows 7, and Windows 8.1 installed in 2 different partitions with dual boot and have a third partition to save shared files in the machine to access easily from each of the OS'. If I install a program (not portable one) will it work with the other OS that didn't install that program?
Is there any way to do this besides portable software?

Comment: I guess if it did work maybe then it'd be portable?  (like just running from files in a specific place and relative to some parent directory)..   Or you could run it in a VM.

Comment: Another thing to consider (though probably not what you're looking for), is an application server like citrix, though I don't know much about it/them and I don't think it's what you are looking for, as with that I think a host application server (eg citrix?) is installed in one place(a thick server) and just accessed from others(thin clients), not installed on the clients. Though I haven't got a clue about them so i'm not even sure if that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works well on a dual-boot Linux/Windows machine. *IrfanView* is an excellent Windows image editor which comes in an installer. Linux wine can run it directly from the NTFS disk (as opposed to ext4 file system used in this Linux box), though it has not been installed under Linux. *7-Zip* is another application that can be used the same way.

That said, many programs *require* individual installation to set Registry keys, to set paths and to validate licenses. It might be *possible* to run something like MS *Word* on a different drive, but it would require considerable hacking to do so.